# Can't get IValueProvider values from QueryStringValueProvider(ControllerContext) in Unit Testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing

Here is the Test method Creating a mock for request and context 
have added the querystring to the context and while debugging the TestMethod could able to see the values of the querystring collection

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Save_Tester()
    {
        //Arrange                         
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        string querystring = "?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4";

        Mock<HttpRequestBase> mock_request = MockHelpers.CreateMockRequest(querystring);
        Mock<HttpContextBase> mock_context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

        //Request
        NameValueCollection myValues = new NameValueCollection();            
        FormCollection formcollection = new FormCollection(myValues);
        mock_request.SetupGet(mr => mr.Params).Returns(myValues);
        mock_request.SetupGet(mr => mr.Form).Returns(myValues);
        mock_request.SetupGet(mr => mr.QueryString).Returns(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring));

        //Context            
        mock_context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(mock_request.Object);
        controller.ValueProvider = formcollection.ToValueProvider();

        // Act                                              
        Assert.IsNotNull(controller); //Guard
        var result_query = controller.Save() as ViewResult;

        // Assert            
    }
```

In the save method using QueryStringValueProvider to get the Values but has no namevaluecollection
QueryStringValueProvider takes the ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString that to avail in debugging

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{
  try
  {                
   IValueProvider provider = new QueryStringValueProvider(this.ControllerContext);
   //provider has no namevaluecollection values
  }
  catch 
  {
   throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `Mock<ControllerContext>` whose HttpContext property returns your current mock_context, and then setting `controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext`?

Comment: Found the bug I haven't assigned **HttpContext.Current** with Request QueryString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solution**

This solved it I should have taken some time to analyse before putting a question

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&&key4=value4");

HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, uri.ToString(),
                                            uri.Query.TrimStart('?'));

HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));

HttpSessionStateContainer sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id",
                                        new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                        new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
                                        10, true, HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                        SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(
                                             httpContext, sessionContainer);


HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
```